# When i try to npm install or npm install <any-package>, i see "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')" and İ have package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-install

When I try to npm install or npm install, I see "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')" and I have package.json I add screenshots, please help me, thanks a lot.

And that's my error log.

```
`0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   'react-scripts'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.2
2 info using node@v16.13.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\muhammed.eviz\Desktop\HAKİM\hakim-ui\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\muhammed.eviz\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\muhammed.eviz\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 13ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
29 timing idealTree:init Completed in 10ms
30 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
31 silly idealTree buildDeps
32 silly fetch manifest @reduxjs/toolkit@^1.6.2
33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@reduxjs%2ftoolkit 444ms (cache revalidated)
34 timing idealTree Completed in 464ms
35 timing command:install Completed in 478ms
36 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
36 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1282:38)
36 verbose stack     at Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1103:30)
36 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:930:11)
36 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)
36 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
36 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:149:5)
36 verbose stack     at async Install.install (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:170:5)
37 verbose cwd C:\Users\muhammed.eviz\Desktop\HAKİM\hakim-ui
38 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
39 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-scripts"
40 verbose node v16.13.1
41 verbose npm  v8.1.2
42 error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')
43 verbose exit 1`
```

[error screenshot1 - when npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eFVB.png)

[error screenshot2 - when npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4w6t.png)

[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE5hO.png)

Comment: Are you running script in correct path?

Share more data about repository do you working on it like files structures

Comment: Yes, I am running correct path and you can see on screenshot, thanks for answer, İ add some screenshots again now @SaeedHemmati

Comment: I added folder structure screen

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling npm and node?

Comment: What is version of installed npm and node?

Comment: I've tried to reinstall npm and node and versions npm:8.1.2 and node:v16.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to install some packages to a project path which has non-Unicode characters like the following in the path's name

```
ÇŞİĞÜæÂÊ...
```

you will get errors.

The below path will work if you try to install packages here.

```
C:\Users\andrew\project
```

But this path will not work because it has Unicode in its name.

```
C:\Users\ândrew\project
```

EDIT: The best way of solve this problem is using memory card. (Like C:, D:, F:...)

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think you can avoid using this type of sentence when you answer a question.
> If you need this answer now, here the answer

This type of sentence is irrelevant and at first read, it may sound a bit aggressive. I know you may not mean it. But better to avoid confusion 

Comment: Also what do you mean by "The best way of solve this problem is using memory card. (Like C:, D:, F:...)"? How does this solve the problem?

Comment: what is your path of your project?